# Boost.Python - How to re-enter module scope?

Tags: c++, python, scope, boost-python

I'm exposing some C++ classes to Python that have nested `enum`'s. Looking at the example documentation at [boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/object.html) and [wiki.python.org](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/module), I can't see how to leave a scope once it has been entered, in order to go back to the global / module scope. Instead, each subsequent scope gets nested within the previous one.

As an example:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:
    enum Choose { eFoo, eBar };

    /* Default constructor with enum as required argument */
    Foo(Choose choice): m_choice(choice) {}
    ~Foo() {}

    Choose get() const { return m_choice; }

private:
    const Choose m_choice;

};


class Bar
{
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    scope global;

    /* Define Foo class, and a scope to go with it. */
    scope in_Foo = class_<Foo>
        ("Foo", init<Foo::Choose>())
        .def("rovalue", &Foo::get)
        ;

    /* Expose 'Choose' enum as Foo.Choose */
    enum_<Foo::Choose>("Choose")
        .value("Foo", Foo::eFoo)
        .value("Bar", Foo::eBar)
        ;

    /* How to get back to module scope??  */
    global;
    scope();

    /* This currently is exposed as Foo.Bar, but should just be Bar */
    class_<Bar>("Bar", init<>())
        ;
}
```

I've tried changing that `global;` line to various things, but all to the same result:

```bash
$ g++ -fPIC -shared scope.cpp -o foo.so -lpython2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lboost_python
$ python -c 'import foo; print "Bar" in dir(foo)'
False
$ python -c 'import foo; print "Bar" in dir(foo.Foo)'
True
```

**EDIT:**

Having had another look at wiki.python.org, it would seem that in the above example, the correct answer would be to use `scope within(global)` to revert to the module level scope. Indeed, this works for the above example. Unfortunately however, I get a compile error when I use it in my actual application..

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost;
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)
{
    python::scope module_level;
    /* .... */
    python::scope python::within(module_level);
    /* ... */
}
```

Compile error:

```
error: invalid use of qualified-name 'boost::python::within'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ironically, and possibly too clever for its own good, this can be accomplished using C++ scope.  The [`boost::python::scope`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/scope.html#scope-spec) documentation states that when the lifetime of a `scope` object ends, the current scope reverts to what it was before the `scope` object was constructed.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)              // set scope to foo
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  {
    scope in_Foo = class_<Foo>        // define foo.Foo and set scope to foo.Foo
        ("Foo", init<Foo::Choose>())
        .def("rovalue", &Foo::get)
        ;

    enum_<Foo::Choose>("Choose")     // define foo.Foo.Choose
        .value("Foo", Foo::eFoo)
        .value("Bar", Foo::eBar)
        ;
  }                                  // revert scope, setting scope to foo

  class_<Bar>("Bar", init<>())       // define foo.Bar
      ;
}
```

While `scope` objects could have their lifetime managed through other means, I find that using `scope` objects as automatic variables within C++ scope provides some parallelism to C++ namespaces.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a complete beginner with C++, so still need to get the hang of a lot of these cunning language features. This works well and as expected though!

Comment: Less "Ironically, and possibly too clever" and more "this is exactly the intent of this object."